# I modify one numpy array but it modifies 2...?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a strange behavior with my numpy array modification. It is probably a "normal" behavior in python but I am not really used to this langage:

```
B=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

b=np.asarray(B)
c=b
print("I display b :")
print(b)
c[0,0]=-c[0,0] # I multiply this coordinates by -1


print("I display c (modified at the right place : ok)")
print(c)
print("But b has also been modified ???!!!")
print(b)
```

The outputs :

```
    I display b :
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
I display c (modified at the right place : ok)
[[-1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9]]
But b has also been modified ???!!!
[[-1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9]]
```

Why b has been modified even if I never changed it ? I only changed c...?

Comment: `c=b` **does not** create a new object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since python works by reference, when you're setting `c=b` they're both referencing the same object. So a change to c would affect b.
You might want to do the following:

```
import copy
c = copy.copy(b)
```

This will make c as a new object and modifying it won't affect b anymore.

Or using numpy:

```
c = np.copy(b)
```

Comment: numpy has its own copy function. It's unclear which would be more performant, though. I would assume numpy's, but that would be worth profiling if performance were an issue.

Comment: True, but if the sizes where as in his example, I believe the difference would be negligible.

Comment: Yes, of course. People often post stripped-down examples here when they have much larger problems, though, and other people with large problems may come across this answer.

Answer (score 1):

c is just an alias. If you want to copy the array, use c = np.copy(b).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to already mentioned copy methods, you can create a copy for variable `c` like this:

```
B=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b=np.asarray(B)
c = b.copy()

c[1, 1] = 15
print(b)
print(c)
```

Will give you output like this:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
[[ 1  2  3]
 [ 4 15  6]
 [ 7  8  9]]
```